# Node and MQTT, do something on message

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am building a specific device based on Node, Cylon and am publishing events to a MQTT broker. I'd like to know how to perform a certain action once a certain MQTT message comes to the device. Can anybody point me in the right direction? I'm a bit lost in the matter ;)

I use this to publish data:

```
mqtt.publish(thingTopic,  JSON.stringify(data));
```

I'd like to create something like this:

```
if certain message arrives at broker -> do a post or get request to internal url.
```

The question is a bit vague, i must admit...

Answer (score 3):

You would probably need to build your own custom MQTT broker to achieve what you are looking for which is not really the point of the [pub/sub message paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern). Instead of customizing the MQTT broker, look into creating your own subscribing application that will react to messages being received from the MQTT Broker.

Hopefully the following sequence diagram will help understand.

[image: Sequence Diagram]

Comment: Thanks Pierre-Luc,
That is exactly what i would like to do :) I'm looking into writing a program that interprets specific MQTT values to a certain command/node action. However, i'm still researching howto do just that.

Comment: I can think of different ways to achieve that. For example, you could have multiple subscriber applications with different subscriptions, (e.g. action1, action2, ...). Each application could do something different upon the reception of a message. You could also add information in the payload of the messages and have your client application react differently to different payloads. Designing a solid topic hierarchy is key along with useful message payloads.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of got me in the right direction :) if i find something working, i'll post it here.